# Use the result of an async API call inside a forEach

Tags: javascript, api, axios

I am calling an API that return a list of users as follows:

```
const users = await axios.get('/api/users/all');
```

res.data now is an array of my users who each have a field called manager that is an id of a manager from another Schema
I have another API that returns a manager name when their id is provided

```
axios.get('/api/managers/managerName', id)
```

I want to run a forEach to insert the manager name to my result instead of his id.
I am trying

```
const users= await axios.get('/api/users/all');
const final = users.data.forEach(function (element) {
      element.managerName= axios.get('/api/managers/managerName', element.id);
    });
```

But of course this doesnt work since `axios.get('/api/managers/managerName', element.id)` returns a promise.
How can i fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell,  you can't use `await` inside `forEach` or `map`. It doesn't work (doesn't await). You have to use a `for` loop.

```
for( let element of users.data) {
    element.managerName = await axios.get('/api/managers/managerName', element.id);
}
```

Comment: This worked great but the api return a result with an id and a name when i should only use name to fill `element.managerName`
is there a way to pull that? putting .data.name after the get doesnt work
Thank you so much!

Comment: i made my api to return only the name but still the result of the await are put in `data`

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! I had forEach loop & using await inside and gave me an error: await can be used within an async block only 
But after converting to this no longer error and await works as expected. (But yes function containing loop is type of async )

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your second promise:

```
const final = users.data.forEach(async function (element) {
      element.managerName= await axios.get('/api/managers/managerName', element.id).then((manager) => manager.name);
    });
```

Comment: async function (element) - function inside forEach should be also async

Comment: Except, unless I'm mistaken, you can't use `await` inside `forEach`. It doesn't work (doesn't await). You have to use a `for` loop.

Comment: you cant put await inside forEach :(

Answer (score 1):

```
const users= await axios.get('/api/users/all');
const final = Promise.all(
users.data.map(async (element) => {
      element.managerName = await axios.get('/api/managers/managerName', element.id);
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you! Running this I am getting promise when i `console.log(final)`

Comment: put await before Promise.all